# Online resources for reviewing graphics cards for GPGPU

Tags: hpc

Can anyone recommend a site that maintains up-to-date reviews of graphics cards for GPGPU use? Most benchmarks focus on gaming performance, whereas I am interested in the performance of scientific applications like FFTs, linear algebra, and image/video processing.

I want to know how the performance varies for scientific applications (as opposed to games) with price so I can budget effectively.

Comment: Can you specify more? Basically there are two vendors and it's not a problem to find summary information on their sites.

Comment: I'm sure you can ask there: http://forums.nvidia.com/ for a specific review or recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the answer depends on how you define *review*. If you mean benchmarks, then there are numerous sites which have up-to-date benchmarks of GPU cards. One of them is [VideoCardBenchMark.com](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/). A list of GPUs is maintained on that site. Also, there is the typical chart like [the one on bang-per-buck](http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/video_lookup.php?gpu=GeForce+GTX+680).

A few random website like Toms Hardware do review GPU cards once a while. But those are for gaming and I'm not sure they would meet your requirements.

For scientific computing in GPU, you could probably use [forums of gpgpu.org](http://gpgpu.org/forums/viewforum.php?f=4&sid=6a45e3eecb0155d4f8bfcec1eaea3fe0)

If you want Double Precision performance with GPU cards, its probably best to use nVidia forums instead. Of course, you may find benchmarks at a lot of places.